# C++ - functor vs inline function vs operator overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, inline, functor

Based on various Stack Overflow posts, I put the following together in a license plate recognition program I did a while back:

PossiblePlate.h:

```
(lines omitted)

std::string strChars;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static bool sortDescendingByNumberOfChars(const PossiblePlate &ppLeft, const PossiblePlate &ppRight) {
    return(ppLeft.strChars.length() > ppRight.strChars.length());
}

(lines omitted)
```

Main.cpp

```
(lines omitted)

// sort the vector of possible plates in descending order (most number of chars to least number of chars)
std::sort(vectorOfPossiblePlates.begin(), vectorOfPossiblePlates.end(), PossiblePlate::sortDescendingByNumberOfChars);

(lines omitted)
```

Here is the repo if more context would be helpful:

https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_License_Plate_Recognition_Cpp

This code is great for sorting a vector of objects in C++ based on any member variable, I've re-used it quite a few times since in various other projects.

My question is, what is this?  A functor, inline function, operator overload, or something else entirely?  How could I determine the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i don't understand the question but if *this* refers to std::sort i would say it is a template function [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, what is this? A functor, inline function, operator overload, or something else entirely?

It is just a function, that got converted to a [pointer to function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions). A function pointer can be used in the function call operator, thus it can be used as a comparator for `std::sort`.